# execution of system command from perl script using su

Tags: perl, ksh

I have a perl script as below:
test.pl

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 system("ls -lart");
```

this works fine but when i run it as below it is failing:

```
su guest test.pl
```

it is failing at 2nd line as below:

```
0403-057 Syntax error at line 2 : `(' is not expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man 1 su`:

```
OPTIONS
       The options which apply to the su command are:

       -c, --command COMMAND
           Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its -c.

           The executed command will have no controlling terminal. This option cannot be used to execute interractive programs which need a controlling TTY.
```

So you should use

```
su -c "perl /path/to/test.pl --maybe some.options" guest
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute it using `-c` option for `su`. The problem is that if you launch it like that, it's supposed to be a shell script. So you have to tell `su` to actually load the shell and then execute the command.

Most likely

```
su guest -c test.pl
```

will work (provided it's in the command path of the user, of course).